# Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension throwing error in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm specifically getting this error from the IntegrationTest class that's free to download via the Unity Asset Store.

The specific line that's throwing the error is here:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sceneName);
```

But you can see it here in context.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class DynamicTestAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string m_SceneName;

    public DynamicTestAttribute(string sceneName)
    {
        if (sceneName.EndsWith(".unity"))
            sceneName = sceneName.Substring(0, sceneName.Length - ".unity".Length);
        m_SceneName = sceneName;
    }

    public bool IncludeOnScene(string sceneName)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(sceneName);
        return fileName == m_SceneName;
    }
}
```

The Unity compiler says:

```
Assets/UnityTestTools/IntegrationTestsFramework/TestRunner/IntegrationTest.cs(154,33): error CS0117: `Path' does not contain a definition for `GetFileNameWithoutExtension'
```

According to the Unity documentation this is proper usage. Perhaps there is a new documentation link for Unity 5 that I've missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can solve the error with the line "using Path = System.IO.Path;" at the top of the source file. (I realize in this case it's not your code, but if you want to fix it locally, or anyone else has the problem.)

Thanks to @yoyo for supplying the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the problem was I had just imported the iTween Examples from the Asset Store and it has a class named Path in it so the two class definitions - Unity's default one and the definition in iTweens examples were conflicting and the compiler had decided the iTween one was 'the' one and it didn't contain the method referenced above.

Perhaps I should send the Pixel Placement guys a note about it.

Comment: Good idea, that's naughty of iTween. Note that you can solve the error with the line "using Path = System.IO.Path;" at the top of the source file. (I realize in this case it's not your code, but if you want to fix it locally, or anyone else has the problem.)